# trying to install spacy_langdetect and langid over pycharm with no succses

Tags: python, pycharm, spacy

for some reason those modules dont exist in my Pycharm interpeter, while i do mangae to pip install them 
so i cant use [my script(as in the picture u can see the interpeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDssa.png)them inside pycharm

```
import spacy
from spacy_langdetect import LanguageDetector
nlp = spacy.load('he')
#language_detector = language_detector()
nlp.add_pipe(language_detector)
doc = nlp('This is some English text.')

doc._.languages  # ['he']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an installation related issue, you correctly installed spacy_langdetect. It is not shown up under your PyCharm interpreter, because Pycharm treats it as a module under the spacy package, not as a seperate package entirely. If you open the command prompt, navigate to the environment you are using and type `pip list` the spacy-langdetect package will show up.